# Id handling / inserting in multiple tables. (basic forum)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I started to write a forum, because I want to learn a little SQL (MySQL).

So firstly, I have a **posts** table, and there are a `post_id` and `topic_id` columns.

But, on the other side I have a **topics** table.
In the **topics** table I also have a `last_post_id` and `topic_id`, too !

So they are referencing to each other.

So the question is: *When a user creates a topic (and the same time writes the first post), how to INSERT these id's effectively??*

Because now I have to do the following steps:

1. Insert topic related data (topic title..etc, insert last_post_id =0 cause I dont know this value here), then retrieve topic_id
2. Insert post data (text, username.., topic_id), and retieve this particular post_id
3. *Update* **topics** table, with the retrieved post_id (set `last_post_id`).

Isn't it too long, tedious, uneffective..?

Thanks for your time. My english is not the best.. sry.

Comment: You could do it using a single transaction, but the basic idea is the same. You need to insert the new topic before having `topic_id`, and you need to insert the new post before having `last_post_id`. With your current tables, there's no way around that. *Edit to add: You could also use a [`TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html) that automatically updates the `last_post_id` field when a new record is added to `posts`. That doesn't change the number of queries executed, but it would be handled transparently by MySQL itself.

Comment: @MartinodF: Do you want to put that down as an answer? I was writing up pretty much the same thing (even the trigger!) while you were making your comment.

Comment: @muistooshort I've posted it as an answer, a bit late perhaps :) Your point about using NULL is a good idea too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using a single transaction, but the basic idea is the same. You need to insert the new topic before having `topic_id`, and you need to insert the new post before having `last_post_id`. With your current tables, there's no way around that.

You could also use a [`TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html) that automatically updates the `last_post_id` field when a new record is added to `posts`. That doesn't change the number of queries executed, but it would be handled transparently by MySQL itself.

Also, the point raised by mu is too short in his answer about setting `last_post_id` to `NULL` is a good idea.

Comment: I'm just leaving this to you since we're saying the same things and you really did get in first.

Comment: mu, why u deleted ? :)) I 've just started to read that foreign key thingy.. Can't I find the deleted post under your actions tab?? -- @MartinodF thanks:)

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort, very kind of you! @CriticalPoint about foreign keys, if you're using InnoDB you should make sure that `topics.last_post_id` is declared as a foreign key referencing `post.post_id`, and that `post.topic_id` is referencing `topics.topic_id`. You can define what to do when these relationships would be broken by an UPDATE or DELETE, for example to delete all posts with a certain `topic_id` when that topic is deleted. Be sure to read about foreign keys!

Answer (score 0):

last_post_id is meaningless, and just extra work. Instead you should grab the last post for a specific topic dynamically, whenever you need it. There's no reason to store it in the database.

About the topic / post, the normal procedure is to create the topic if it doesn't exist, grab the created id, and insert a new post with that topic Id, just like you said.

Comment: Yes, sounds reasonable.. but phpBB has the last_post_id in the topics table, too :D -- as i saw the database structure

Comment: It's not meaningless. It's certainly not normalized, but it saves a query (something like `SELECT MAX(id) FROM posts WHERE topic_id = X`.). It's a trade-off and you have to make sure your `last_post_id` is kept up to date correctly, but it has a reason to exist :)

Comment: @MartinodF, If you store the last_post_id in the topic table, you still have to query the post table to get the user/post/date or whatever you want to get. If you instead query the post table with something like `select user,date from posts where topic_id = $topic_id order_by date desc limit 1` you don't put more pressure on the server, do you?

Comment: You can use a join to get that information in a single query. `SELECT topics.*, posts.user, posts.date FROM topics INNER JOIN posts ON topics.last_post_id = posts.post_id WHERE topics.topic_id = X`. I'm not arguing that this is a better solution, just that it's viable. One should evaluate advantages and disadvantages of both before deciding on which to settle :)

Comment: I do agree that you can use join. It doesn't sound like good practice, but it's server-friendly. Isn't there a way to get the topic and latest post in the same query, without storing the latest_id? I guess you would have to use some kind of mysql loops?

Comment: how about joining the topics table with a subquery table that grabs the posts, groups the posts by topic_id and sorts by date?

Comment: You could use something like `SELECT topics.*, posts.* FROM topics INNER JOIN posts ON topics.topic_id = posts.topic_id WHERE topics.topic_id = X SORT BY posts.date DESC LIMIT 1`. The problem with that query is that LIMIT is applied after scanning all of the matching `posts` rows, so it can take quite a bit longer. A similar approach, `SELECT topics.*, posts.* FROM topics INNER JOIN posts ON posts.post_id = (SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE topic_id = topics.topic_id SORT BY date DESC LIMIT 1) WHERE topics.topic_id = X` is still very slow, as it needs to fire a separate sorted query.

Comment: The best solution would be to use `MAX()`, assuming post_id is monotonically increasing. `SELECT topics.*, posts.* FROM topics INNER JOIN posts ON posts.post_id = (SELECT MAX(post_id) FROM posts WHERE topic_id = topics.topic_id) WHERE topics.topic_id = X`, but it still counts as an extra query, compared to a join :) Sorry for the huge reply!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8244/discussion-between-martinodf-and-joakimdahlstrom)